# dealing with many evaluations?

Tags: python

Are there more elegant ways to deal with having to evaluate many cases?

This seems too ugly and not the most efficient. Do seasoned Python3 programmers
work some kind of voodoo with list comprehensions to do intense evaluations?

sample file is at the bottom.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

#This utility attempts to parse the output text files generated by dcp_inspect
#for faster inspection and when attending to multiple DCP inspections.
#dcp_inspect_parse runs on Python3.x (Though I am testing on 3.3)
#
#
#
#
#
#

import glob
import os
import sys
print(os.getcwd())


cpl                  = []
content              = []
contentkind          = []
container            = []
errors               = [] 
package              = []
summary              = []
mainsound            = []
mainpicture          = []
encryption           = []
duration             = []
fsp                  = []
dimensiontype        = []
aspect               = []
filesize             = [2]
audio                = []
cpltype              = []

dir= []
dir=input("Please enter directory location of dcp_inspect output***\n")

print('Changing directories')
os.chdir(dir)
print(os.getcwd())

print('Attempting to open file(s) in directory:\n')
print(dir,'\n')

for file in glob.glob("*"):
    try:
        newfile = file
        print("Scanning...\t\t\t\t\t\t", newfile)
        data = open(newfile)
        for each_line in data:
            if 'summary'in each_line:
                summary.extend(each_line.split())
            elif 'Errors' in each_line:
                errors=(each_line.split())
            elif 'Package with total size'in each_line:
                if 'Bytes 0' in each_line:
                    continue
                else:
                    temp =[]
                    temp.extend(each_line.split())
                    #print(len(temp))
                    filesize=(temp.pop()+' '+temp.pop())
                    #print('size =',size)
            elif 'MainSound'in each_line:
                if 'audio' in each_line:
                    if '24bps' in each_line:
                        if '48kHz' in each_line:
                            if '6ch' in each_line:
                                if '16ch' in each_line:
                                    temp = []
                                    temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                    audio = '16ch 48kHz 24bps'

                                elif '6ch' in each_line:
                                    temp = []
                                    temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                    audio = '6ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '7ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '7ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '8ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '8ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '10ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '10ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '11ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '11ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '12ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '12ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '13ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '13ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '14ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '14ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '15ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '15ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '16ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '16ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '17ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '17ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '18ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '18ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '19ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '19ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '20ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '20ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '21ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '21ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '22ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '22ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '23ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '23ch 48kHz 24bps'

                            elif '24ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '24ch 48kHz 24bps'

                        elif '96kHz' in each_line:
                            audio = 'unknown format, bitrate, etc'
                            if '6ch'in each_line:
                                if '16ch' in each_line:
                                    temp = []
                                    temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                    audio = '16ch 96kHz 24bps'

                                elif '26ch' in each_line:
                                    temp = []
                                    temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                    audio = '26ch 96kHz 24bps'

                                elif '6ch' in each_line:
                                    temp = []
                                    temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                    audio = '6ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '7ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '7ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '8ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '8ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '9ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '9ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '10ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '10ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '11ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '11ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '12ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '12ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '13ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '13ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '14ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '14ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '15ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '15ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '16ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '16ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '17ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '17ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '18ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '18ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '19ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '19ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '20ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '20ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '21ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '21ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '22ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '22ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '23ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '23ch 96kHz 24bps'

                            elif '24ch'in each_line:
                                temp = []
                                temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                                audio = '24ch 96kHz 24bps'

            elif 'MainPicture'in each_line:
                if 'pictures' in each_line:
                    temp = []
                    temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
                    container = temp[-2]
                    encryption= temp[-3]

            elif 'CPL Id:'in each_line:
                cpl=(each_line.split())

            elif 'CPL type: 'in each_line:
                cpltype=(each_line.split())
                cpltype = cpltype[2]

            elif 'ContentKind: 'in each_line:
                contentkind=(each_line.split())
                contentkind = contentkind[1]

            elif 'ContentTitleText:'in each_line:
                content=(each_line.split(':'))
                content = content[1]



        for x in range(len(summary)):
            if 'fps' in summary[x]:
                #print(summary[(x-1)],'near fps')
                #print(summary[x],'near fps')
                fps = summary[(x-1)]
                duration = summary[(x-2)].strip()


            elif 'summary:' in summary[x]:
                #print(summary[(x)])
                content = summary[(x+1)]
                content.strip(',')

            elif '2D' in summary[x]:
                #print(summary[(x)], 'found')
                dimensiontype = summary[(x)]

                aspect = summary[(x+1)].strip(',')
            elif '3D' in summary[x]:
                #print(summary[(x)], 'found')
                dimensiontype = summary[(x)]
                aspect = summary[(x+1)]


        print('Container:             \t\t',container.strip())        
        print('CPL Type:              \t\t',cpltype)
        print('Duration:              \t\t',duration.strip(','))
        print('Frame Rate:            \t\t',fps)
        print('Aspect Ratio:          \t\t',aspect.strip(','))
        print('Dimension:             \t\t',dimensiontype.strip(',')) 
        print('Content Title:         \t\t',content.strip(',').strip('""'))
        print('Audio for DCP:         \t\t', audio)
        print('Package size:          \t\t',filesize)
        print('Encryption status:     \t\t',encryption.upper().strip())       
        print('CPL ID:                \t\t', cpl[2])  
        print('Content Kind:          \t\t',contentkind.upper()) 
        print('\n')
        print('There are',errors[1],'Errors and',errors[3],'hints for', content.strip(','))
        if errors[1] != '0':
            print('could be issues\n')
        else:
            print('This DCP appears to be OK\n')
            #print(summary)


        data.close()

    except:
        print("Exception Encountered")
        pass
```

Found 1 Assetmap
 AM 7599203f-a73f-4c55-b967-93c3061e10ea: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/ASSETMAP
 AM 7599203f-a73f-4c55-b967-93c3061e10ea lists 4 assets:
 cef846b8-8f85-4cb4-9cb8-f39e53ebe013: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/cef846b8-8f85-4cb4-9cb8-f39e53ebe013_pcm.mxf
 c2cb9f04-83bf-4829-b4cf-e9963dbaa0d3: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/c2cb9f04-83bf-4829-b4cf-e9963dbaa0d3_j2c.mxf
 d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml
 edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml
 Assetmap 7599203f-a73f-4c55-b967-93c3061e10ea lists 1 PKL:
 PKL file present: edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml

Found 1 Package
 PKL file present: edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml

PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: Schema check: OK
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: No Signature node found
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: AnnotationText: OVERNIGHTERS_20140108
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a lists 3 assets
 cef846b8-8f85-4cb4-9cb8-f39e53ebe013: application/x-smpte-mxf;asdcpKind=Sound: 
 d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: text/xml;asdcpKind=CPL: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml
  [...] g hash value:   0% [                    ] ETA --:--:-- Elapsed --:--:--] g hash value:  16% [====                ] ETA 00:00:00 Elapsed 00:00:00A 00:00:00 Elapsed 00:00:00
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: Package size: 93.9 GB
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a lists 1 composition
 CPL file present: d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml

Found 1 Composition
 CPL file present: d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml

CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: Audio analysis ...
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: Audio analysis: Done
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Schema check: OK
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: No Signature node found
 CPL Id:           d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118
 CPL file:         /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml
 CPL type:         Interop (http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CPL-20040511#)
 ContentTitleText: OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV
 AnnotationText:   [Empty]
 ContentKind:      feature
 IssueDate:        2014-01-08T17:49:36-08:00 (Wednesday Jan 8 2014 17:49)
 Issuer:           Colorflow Digital
 Creator:          Colorflow
 Number of Reels:  1
 Reel 1:
 145729  01:41:12+01 @ 24.0  c2cb9f04  MainPicture  (MXF Interop, 01:43:53+18, plaintext, 1920x1080, pictures)
 145729  01:41:12+01 @ 24.0  cef846b8  MainSound    (MXF Interop, 01:43:53+18, plaintext, 6ch 48kHz 24bps, [FAIL], [FAIL], audio)
 Total duration:
 145729  01:41:12+01 @ 24.0
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Composition summary: "OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV", Interop, Plaintext, 2D, HD, HD, 01:41:12+01, 24.0 fps
 Composition complete

Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: MainPicture has non-DCI aspect ratio 1.778 (1920x1080, HD): Playback with proper non-standard masking recommended
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: MainPicture has non-DCI pixel dimensions (1920x1080, HD)
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: ContentTitleText "OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV" is missing some parts
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: 9 parts matching: facility:"CLO" film_title:"OVERNIGHTERS" content_kind:"FTR" aspect_ratio:"F" audio_type:"51" resolution:"2K" studio:"EN" date:"20140108" package_type:"OV"
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: 2 parts missing: language, territory_rating
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: Part aspect_ratio claims Flat but composition aspect ratio is HD
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: Part resolution claims 2K but composition resolution is HD
 Info: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Composition OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV was issued 3 days ago
 Info: dcp_inspect v1.2013.12.16 on Saturday Jan 11 2014 10:57 (00:01:18:46)
 Info: Inspected: /media
 Info: Found 1 Package with total size 93.9 GB
 Info: Found 1 Assetmap, 1 Package (0 signed), 1 Composition (0 signed, 1 plaintext/0 KDMs required)
 Info: 0 Errors, 7 Hints

Comment: What do the `MainSound` lines look like?

Comment: just added a sample file. The problem is there is sometimes variance that is really difficult to account for in these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of testing each case, you could use regex match on the values:

```
m = re.search('([0-9]+)bps', each_line)
if m is None:
    bps = None
else:
    bps = int(m.group(1))

m = re.search('([0-9]+)ch', each_line)
if m is None:
    channels = None
else:
    channels = int(m.group(1))

m = re.search('([0-9]+)kHz', each_line)
if m is None:
    bandwidth = None
else:
    bandwidth = int(m.group(1))

# if still needed
audio = '%ich %ikHz %ibps' % (channels, bandwidth, bps)
```

You can also match the whole line if it's still in the same format I can see [here](https://github.com/wolfgangw/backports/wiki/Example-output-from-dcp_inspect):

```
patt = '''MainSound\s*\(.*([0-9]+) channels, ([0-9]+) kHz, ([0-9]+) bps, audio\)'''
m = re.search(patt, each_line)
if m:
    channels, bandwidth, bps = m.groups()
```

Alternatively if you know exactly what the line will look like, you could use [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your program could trivially be simplified by factoring out

```
temp = []
temp.extend(each_line.split(','))
```

from each `elif` and instead writing it once above or below the elif sections.

Often parsing like this can be improved by splitting the source into chunks and then using the chunks as keys to a dictionary of functions (or, in your case, a dictionary of strings might work too, because all of the terminal functions differ only in their strings).  See for instance [this blog post](http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2007/06/24/using-dictionaries-rather-than-complex-if-elif-else-clauses/) for an example.  As long as the input is regular-ish, this is probably your best path to a good refactor.  Instead of flow control, think data structure -- build a small program around a data structure mapping input to output, rather than a large program that embeds the mapping in program code.